# Flaky cypress test with Svelte: Button is sometimes clicked, sometimes not

Tags: cypress, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I am testing my SvelteKit site with Cypress. I sometimes experience flaky tests, similar to what has been described here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/. In short, Cypress sometimes finds and clicks a button before the event listeners are attached - as a result, the click goes nowhere. The proposed solution is to simply re-try clicking until the appropriate listeners have been attached. That works in my case as well. However, though I do understand why this can be an issue in the example given in the blog post (it's a large calendar modal), I find it hard to justify that this issue arises when using a simple Svelte button.

Here is a simple example of a button that reveals some content when clicked:

```html
<script>
  let hide = true;
</script>

<button
  on:click={() => {
    console.log('clicked');
    hide = false;
  }}>
  Show
</button>

<span class:hide>Content</span>

<style>
  .hide {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

The corresponding test sometimes passes, sometimes fails:

```js
it('reveals content on click', () => {
  cy.contains('Show').click();
  cy.contains('Content').should('be.visible');
});
```

Again, I am aware this can be fixed by re-trying to click the button. And if this is what it takes to make Cypress work with Svelte/SvelteKit, then that's fine with me. But I am wondering: Why would this even be an issue?

Minimal reproduction repo: https://github.com/sophiamersmann/test-svelte-kit-cypress

Comment: I can't reproduce - repl'd your code and added your test. Two questions - where is your `cy.visit()` and how do you use sveltekit (repl only include svelte)

Comment: Here is a GitHub repo that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/sophiamersmann/test-svelte-kit-cypress This is a simple SvelteKit + Cypress setup. Re-run the test and it will eventually fail. I've also tried the same with Svelte (not SvelteKit) and could not reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Another option is [https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-svelte-unit-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-svelte-unit-test). It uses rollup, so you won't get loading issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SvelteKit will by default do server side rendering (SSR), which means the complete HTML is sent to the browser, including the button. That HTML then needs to be hydrated afterwards to become interactive. This means that some code runs so that Svelte connects to the HTML that already exists. Cypress is likely "too fast" here and clicks the button before that hydration step is completed, therefore nothing happens.

It does not happen with pure Svelte because there's no SSR involved. There's a blank index.html page initially which is completely filled by Svelte's JavaScript inside the browser, so the moment the button is visible, the event listener and everything else is already initialized by Svelte.

###### Comparison by steps:

SvelteKit with SSR:

1. Go to page X
2. Page X is rendered on the server
3. Page X is sent to the browser, with the complete HTML
4. Svelte hydrates the HTML (Race condition with Cypress' click test)
5. Completed

Pure Svelte or SvelteKit without SSR:

1. Go to page X
2. Blank page is sent to the browser
3. Svelte constructs and initializes the HTML inside the browser (No race condition with Cypress' click test)
4. Completed

Comment: But why does it not happen with Svelte?

Comment: I added more details to the answer

Comment: Ohh, it makes sense that this is related to hydration. Thank you for taking the time to give such a detailed response. Cheers!

Comment: This makes no sense - why would a simple click handler be hydrated?

Comment: Agreed, there's nothing to substantiate this, it's pure supposition and contrary to my tests.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, but it doesn't really help. "Svelte constructs HTML inside the browser" - why does the test find the button but not it's click handler?

Comment: Hydration = Svelte takes over the rendered HTML. As long as that didn't happen yet, there's no event handler attached to the button. Event handler = Javascript = part of the hydration process.

Comment: But how would one work around this issue? How to ensure that hydration has passed before executing any specs?

Comment: @dummidum - that's not how hydration works.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem lies with Vite, which uses ES modules to load the page and it's components.

Adding an intercept before the cy.visit() seems to give consistent results.
(Note the URL to intercept may vary, you can get it from the last entry in devtools Network).

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('index.svelte?svelte&type=style&lang.css').as('svelte')
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.wait('@svelte')
});
```

Using [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep#burn) to burn-test

```js
npx cypress run --env burn=100
```

##### With intercept

[image]

##### Without intercept

[image]

---

#### Why is it not hydration?

If you create an equivalent Svelte app with `hydratable` set to `true`, it will pass the burn test - IMO because it uses `rollup` instead of `vite` to deliver the app to the browser.

[image]

Comment: It's hydration. The interception works because this makes Cypress wait longer before executing the test. You could intercept similar requests for Vite.

Comment: No, Svelte with hydration passes the burn test (see above).

Comment: Point is, to make the test work you have to wait anyway, if it's by the method given by @SophiaMersmann or by intercepting the ESM fetch. The only difference is the amount of code you need to write to do so.

Comment: Adding "hydratable: true" to your compiler options changes nothing, because you still start from an empty page. You need the server to render the full HTML and send that to the browser to take advantage of the hydratable option. The rollup template doesn't do this.

Comment: No, your "empty page" theory is not correct because the test immediately finds the button but not it's click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Component

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'; // <- Here

  let init = false;
  onMount(() => {
      init = true;
  });

  let hide = true;
</script>

<button
  data-init={init}
  on:click={() => {
    console.log('clicked');
    hide = false;
  }}>
  Show
</button>

<span class:hide>Content</span>

<style>
  .hide {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Cypress

```
it('reveals content on click', () => {
  cy.get('[data-init=true]').should('exist'); // <- Here
  cy.contains('Show').click();
  cy.contains('Content').should('be.visible');
});
```