# cy.type() runs one way when run locally but fails when run by github actions

Tags: cypress, github-actions, vite, sveltekit

My goal is to run my cypress tests during each pull request into a github repo. My expectation is that the cypress tests will run the same locally as they do on the remote github server. The actual result is that they run differently.

I have a minimum reproducible example available [here](https://github.com/plutownium/cypress-gh-actions-failure/pull/2).

The highlights:

Here's how we inform Github of our intent to run the tests. This file works but perhaps the issue is that I need to add another step here:

```
name: run-tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]  # says "run when there's a PR req into the master branch"

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Run cypress tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5.1.0
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm run dev
```

Here is the cypress test I run, in `foo.cy.js`:

```
describe('Some Test', () => {
    it('correctly states that the btn is enabled', () => {
      cy.visit("localhost:5173")
      cy.get("h1").should("exist")
      cy.get("button").should("not.be.enabled")
      cy.get("input").type("cat, hat, jazz")
      cy.wait(500).then(() => {
        cy.get("button").should("be.enabled")
      })
    })
  })
```

And here's the code it's testing

`+page.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    let text = ""
</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>

<input bind:value={text}/>

<button disabled={text.length === 0}>Button!</button>
```

On local, all the tests pass. On remote, it fails saying

```
 1) Some Test
       correctly states that the btn is enabled:
     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<button>' to be 'enabled'
      at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/foo.cy.js:8:25)
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried putting `cy.wait` on a separate line.

```
cy.wait(500)
cy.get("button").should("be.enabled") // doesn't help
```

2. I've tried [running it headed and headless](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8795) meaning I added `command: npx cypress run --headed --browser chrome` to the github action. It still failed.

edit: I discovered that the text I enter using `cy.get("input").type("cat, hat, jazz")` is cleared after the `cy.wait()` command. I discovered this by viewing the output video of the Cypress test run. Will post the full solution when I uncover it.

Edit2: So I removed `cy.wait()` and the issue persisted. Thus I now have:

```
cy.get("input").type("cat, hat, jazz")
# in between the end of the prev line and
# the end of the next line, the values typed
# on the prev line are cleared.
# I don't understand why.
cy.get("button").should("be.enabled")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a issue with Vite and ES6 modules causing tests to be flaky. You can overcome it by adding an intercept at the top of the test, which ensures that Vite has fully loaded the app before you start testing.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept({pathname: '**/+page.svelte*'}).as('svelte')
  cy.visit('http://localhost:5173/')
  cy.wait('@svelte')
})
```

---

Ref: [Flaky cypress test with Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005226/flaky-cypress-test-with-svelte-button-is-sometimes-clicked-sometimes-not)

Basically, to find the URL for the intercept you need to issue a `cy.visit()` then look towards the bottom of devtools Network tab.

In your case, in Svelte dev mode the intercept corresponds to the "route" folder in the source tree, so it's easy to spot.

Comment: It should be `cy.intercept({pathname: '**/+page.svelte'}).as('svelte')` for this project, or `**/_page.svelte*` in preview mode (port 4173).

Comment: Ah man... I don't understand why that solution works but it does. Nor do I understand how you discovered it!

Comment: If you can share it'd go a long way to fixing a similar or nigh identical issue on my real project. This solution didn't work there when pasted in

Comment: I took the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025727/20578569). My understanding is that Cypress (generally) waits for the page to load all it's bits before starting, but misses some of the Vite ES6 modules tricks. So you use the intercept to delay the test until all parts have arrived.

Comment: @Blunt is right - I assumed the ES6 module URL is the same for every project but seems not. You basically need to issue a `cy.visit()` then look towards the bottom of devtools Network tab to find the right chunk to intercept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delay` with your type command. As the name suggests it introduces delay between each key press. The value is in milliseconds.

```js
cy.get("input").type("cat, hat, jazz", {delay: 50})
cy.get("button").should("be.enabled")
```